# Zsh show fail every time when I open my terminal

Tags: macos, shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm using a Mac with OS X Yosemite and Zsh.
By accident,I delete the content of three files below:
.bashrc
.bash_profile
.profile
After that ,when I open my terminal.
The Zsh will show fail under the last login information,it confused me ,and I want to know why.

Comment: What do you mean by "fail"?

Comment: the "fail" is a word below the last login information. It just like you entered a wrong command.

Answer (score 8):

You might want to look at a duplicate question: [Zshell starts up with exit status of 1 after uninstalling RVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45421479/zshell-starts-up-with-exit-status-of-1-after-uninstalling-rvm)

It has an answer that solved the issue for me:

> I found a .zlogin file on my system that contained some rvm-related code. I've deleted the code, and the problem is solved!

Answer (score 5):

Zsh (by default) doesn't read from `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, or `.profile`, so the contents of these files shouldn't matter. You also didn't mention *which* `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, and `.profile` were erased… These files exist in both your `/Users/username` directory and `/etc`. The files sourced by zsh at startup are listed in the [OS X zsh man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/zsh.1.html) (`man zsh` in a terminal) under "STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES". The only reason it would call one of the previously mentioned files is if they were explicitly `source`d in one of the default files.

### My suggestions:

- Check the contents of `/etc/zshenv` (this is the only zsh-specific file in my `etc` directory). Mine has only the following:

  ```
  # system-wide environment settings for zsh(1)
  if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
  fi
  ```
- Can you log in at all using zsh? If not, can you log in using another shell? You can do this in the OS X Terminal.app by going to Preferences -> General and changing the option for "Shells open with:" from "Default login shell" to Command (fill in another shell, *i.e.,* `/bin/bash` or `/bin/sh`). If you can log in with any shell, try the following solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26055174/2216427):

  > ### Looking for the error
  >
  > All shell output goes to the terminal, so you could just redirect it
  >   when starting it. As you are looking for error messages during
  >   initialisation, I'd suggest the following procedure:
  >
  > 1. Disable the problematic configurations
  > 2. Open a terminal
  > 3. Check the value of `SHLVL`: `echo $SHLVL`
  > 4. Re-enable the configurations
  > 5. Start a new z-shell from within the running shell with `zsh 2> zsh-error.log`, this redirects *stderr* to the file 'zsh-error.log'.
  > 6. Check the value of `SHLVL` again. If it is bigger then previous value then exit the current shell (`exit`). (Explanation below)
  > 7. Have a look at 'zsh-error.log' in the current directory.
  >
  > If 'zsh-error.log' does not show anything, you may want to run `zsh -x
  >   2> zsh-error.log` in step 5 instead. This provides a complete debug
  >   output of anything zsh does. This can get quite huge.

  As the answer suggests, those logs can get enormous if you are sourcing man files at startup. Just a bare shell should result in a reasonably small log file.
- Finally, you can retrieve a list of all the files sourced by zsh on startup by running `zsh -o sourcetrace`.

Hope this helps.