# Zshell starts up with exit status of 1 after uninstalling RVM

Tags: shell, rvm, zsh

I've just uninstalled rvm—I ran `rvm implode` and removed rvm from `$PATH` in my `.zshrc`, as specified in [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558656/how-can-i-remove-rvm-ruby-version-manager-from-my-system).

Since uninstalling, I've noticed that my shell startup has an exit status of `1`. I've checked this by using `echo $?` after loading the shell—I always get `1` back.

I briefly reinstalled rvm to confirm that's what caused the change, and sure enough, after reinstalling, my exit status was back to zero on startup.

I've tried commenting out my zshell so that there's no customization, but that didn't solve the problem.

What is causing my startup exit status of `1` after uninstalling rvm?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found it! I was looking at the [zshell sourceforge page](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_3.html#SEC3), and I noticed that zsh reads from five different files at startup:

```
$ZDOTDIR/.zshenv
$ZDOTDIR/.zprofile
$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc
$ZDOTDIR/.zlogin
$ZDOTDIR/.zlogout
```

I found a `.zlogin` file on my system that contained some rvm-related code. I've deleted the code, and the problem is solved!

Comment: Omg, this took me so long to figure out! +50